# ¿Cómo hacer que MenuStrip se adapte cuando cambio de tamaño la pantalla?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Les explico, tengo un proyecto hecho en C# y SQL SERVER, tengo una ventana MDIparent que contiene ventanas hijas, hasta alli todo bien. Lo que quiero es hacer que el `MenuStrip` se adapte porque al hacer pequeña la ventana me esconde los elementos, es posible hacerlo responsive?

Les dejo dos imágenes porque las imágenes dicen mas que mil palabras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que propiedad o evento puedo manejar para que no se oculten los elementos del menustrip?

¿O cómo hacer para poner una flecha que indique que hay mas elementos en la barra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion, era algo sencillo pero antes no habia visto esa propiedad. Les dejo dos imagenes ilustrativas.

La propiedad que tenia que cambiar era **LayoutStyle**, la tenia en **HorizontalWithOverFlow** y la tuve que cambiar a **Flow**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para que aparezca una flecha que dé acceso a los elementos que no caben debes activar la propiedad [CanOverflow del control MenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.canoverflow(v=vs.110).aspx).

Además deberás habilitar esta funcionalidad para los menús concretos que quieras que aparezcan al pulsar la flecha a través de la propiedad [Overflow del ToolStripMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.overflow(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me sale que el menuStrip no tiene esa propiedad, esa Propiedad solo la tienen los toolStrip

Comment: Como puedes ver si accedes a la documentación del control el control MenuStrip sí tiene la propiedad CanOverflow. Otra cosa es que no te aparezca en la ventana de propiedades en tiempo de diseño y tengas que establecer el valor por código